# SQL(ite) LIKE Optimization (or any other database really)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

Given a table with one TEXT (single words) column and a maximum of 1 million rows, what's the best way to optimise this query:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM searchIndex
WHERE name LIKE '%q%u%e%r%y%'
ORDER BY (CASE
              WHEN name LIKE 'query' THEN 1
              WHEN name LIKE 'query%' THEN 2
              WHEN name LIKE '%query' THEN 3
              WHEN name LIKE '%query%' THEN 4
              WHEN name LIKE 'q%u%e%r%y%' THEN 5
              ELSE 6
          END);
```

Currently, I am using SQLite. However, I am willing to try any (free) database system and any table structures.

I need this for a Mac OS X application ([a documentation browser](http://kapeli.com/dash)) and it will be used for searching the index of the documentation sets. There won't be many queries running in a given period of time, so concurrent use is not really an issue.

Comment: Does `name` have a maximum length?  Also, are the table contents static or relatively so?  Are you willing to perform precomputations to speed retrieval?

Comment: Also, is there a minimum length of search term (in this case "query") that you will accept?

Comment: `name` does have a maximum length (my estimate would be around 40-50 characters). Basically what I do is build the index and create the table afterwards (all in code). When I create the table, I know exactly what maximum length `name` will have and all the entries in it remain the same after creation. Minimum length is 1. However, if I can optimise it for queries with length > 2 or > 3 and leave it unoptimised otherwise, that's fine.

Comment: Just to make it clear: all entries in the database remain the same for the entire lifetime of the database. All those entries are inserted in code and I already go through them one by one. Performing extensive computations, at database creation/insert time, on each and every value is not a problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what precomputations I could perform?

Comment: Well, you could create a single character index (table with `name`, `character`, `position`) and search for the characters you want in the right order (my first attempt to write that up as an answer failed when the same character occurred more than once in the word).  Or you could precompute all the possible substrings between the minimum and maximum length of the search term (my wife is working on the formula for how many strings that would be for a word of x characters to see if it's reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical way I'm aware of to optimize queries as general as `%q%u%e%r%y%`. But that is almost certainly not a useful query to perform, as it will end up generating tons of irrelevant matches if the indexed column is even somewhat large. (For instance, the text of your question would match against `the alien invasion`, because it happens to contain those letters in that order.)

The SQLite [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extension is likely to be of interest here -- it will allow you to index the words which appear in a column. For the task you're describing, it should be perfect.

Comment: I've already looked into FTS and it can only match whole words and can't do partial matching as far as I can tell. I am dealing with an index of single words (class, method names), so that query does indeed return the results I need (I need partial matching) and the `ORDER BY` does make sure I get the relevant stuff. Using FTS for me would be just like using `WHERE name LIKE 'query'`, as I'm dealing with single words per row and not pieces of text.